# Firebase "No properties to serialize found on class" when attempting to add data to Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

In short, I'm trying to format a user's information into the database so that the data is capitalized when being sent through JSON - Googling told me about the @PropertyName feature, which I've been trying to use to no success. The user class is as follows:

```
class User(@PropertyName("FirstName") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var firstName: String = "",
           @PropertyName("LastName") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var lastName: String = "",
           @PropertyName("Email") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var Email: String = "",
           @PropertyName("PhoneNumber") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var phoneNumber: String = "",
           @PropertyName("Gender") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var Gender: String = "",
           @PropertyName("City") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var City: String = "",
           @PropertyName("DateOfBirth") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var dateOfBirth: String = "",
           @PropertyName("School") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var School: String = "",
           @PropertyName("Work") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var Work: String = "",
           @PropertyName("DateJoined") @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var dateJoined: Long = 0L)
```

When signing up as a new user, the account is created in Firebase, but I receive an error with the following message when attempting to add their information to the Realtime Database: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.android.projectrc.User` - I'm fairly certain it has to do with the PropertyName attribute as this never happened before adding it - but removing it is not an option as I need the data to be formatted a specific way to prevent problems with existing information within the database (currently it is formatted as camel-case, so "firstName" would be the key, when I need it to be "FirstName")

The code where I actually attempt to add the user's information to the DB is these two lines:

```
val user = User(firstName, lastName, email)
//add user info to database
mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).child("UserInfo").setValue(user)
```

The third line also seems to be where the error occurs. Is there some other workaround I can use to resolve this or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please add you database structure.